# Google admob for android without google-services.json

Tags: android, google-play-services, admob

I want to integrate google admob using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) guide. After solving a few issues, gradle now tells me that I need a `google-services.json` file for the process `'app:processDebugGoogleServices'`. To acquire this file I need to go [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) and basically just download it specifically for my app.

Is there a way to use google admob without binding each app with unique `google-services.json` file? I mean am I able to use a single file for different apps or just not use this file at all? As far as I know, there are several ad networks(Appodeal, for example) that use google admob, but to install Appodeal I do not need to use this `google-services.json` at all.

I mean, for Appodeal for each unique app I just need a unique ad unit ID. For Google Admob I need unique ad unit ID and unique `google-services.json`, which is inconvinient for me. Is there a workaroung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey(apiKey)
            .setApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.google_app_id))
            .build();
    return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, firebaseOptions, "MyApp");
```

Comment: 1. I need to compile my project at first, but gradle will not sync without google-services.json; 2. Where do I get apiKey and google_app_id? I have only ad unit id.

Comment: I've mentioned it in the question: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.`

Comment: ok, that's probably being triggered by use of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in your build.gradle file.  Can you try removing this.

Comment: It worked, thank you. What about the ids? Is it nessesary to initialize `FireBase` explicitly?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use `google-services.json` then you need to explicitly initailize Firebase.  You'll still need to provide those IDs.

Comment: Well, your answer is probably correct and I will mark it as the correct one, but I found another solution: I have no need to use FireBase at all. I am going to use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0`